# cakePHP Session login logout  situation

Tags: session, authentication, cakephp-1.3

I just wanna ask help for my problem 
I have a situation here:

Person1 logs in his account with a username and password (for example username="myUsername" and password="myPassword") and Person1 successfuly logs in and Person1's information is stored into a session..

Now after Person1 logsin, Person2 logs in also with the same account (username="myUsername" and password="myPassword")..

What i want is when Person2 logs in, Person1 will be logged out...
how can i do that?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

:D

Answer (score 2):

when Person1 logs in you'll need to store the [session_id](http://api.cakephp.org/class/session-component#method-SessionComponentid) (in the DB) with the id of the user connected. Let's call this table "ConnectedUsers".
If Person1 logs out then delete the row from ConnectedUsers

Now if Person2 logs in, you'll need to look into the ConnectedUsers table to see if the user is already connected. If there's one, then [destroy his session](http://api.cakephp.org/class/session-component#method-SessionComponentdelete) and create the row for Person2

**Problem:** you won't be able to delete the row from ConnectedUsers if a users logs out due to session expire or if he closes the browser. You might need to store the time of the last connection or the ip to check if there's another user connected

Good Luck!